# Block Screen Shot in Android 6 does not work on some devices

Tags: java, android

I have this line of code

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

To block screenshots in Android devices I am using Android SDK 21 and higher and have tested it on Android 5,6,7 devices. On some Android 6 devices (Tablet) this code does not seem to work and screenshots can be taken.
Any suggestions?
Here is the code I use:

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            int flags1 = getWindow().getAttributes().flags;
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
            int flags2 = getWindow().getAttributes().flags;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
            Log.w("first value of flags", String.valueOf(flags1));
            Log.w("second value of flags", String.valueOf(flags2));
            mVisible = true;
            mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
            mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);



            mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    toggle();
                }
            });
  findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
  client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
        }
```

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Name the devices that it does not work on. There is nothing you can really do to block screenshots at that point, but it gives us more information about trying to help prevent this sort of problem in the future.

Comment: Specific Device that it does not work on: Asus Nexus 7 with Android 6.0.1 installed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I created a brand-new app in Android Studio. I added `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);` after `super.onCreate()` in the activity. I ran the app on a Nexus 7 (2013) running Android 6.0.1. I tried to take a screenshot via Android Studio, and it failed. I commented out the `FLAG_SECURE` line, ran the app again, and I can now take a screenshot. Could you explain in greater detail exactly how you are testing this?

Comment: I am using a physical device.I take the screenshot by pressing simultaneously the power button with the volume down button.

Comment: Again, I cannot reproduce your problem. Using the sample app from my previous comment, I get the expected "couldn't capture screenshot" notification.